# How to have like button update page for everyone

Tags: javascript, html, server

I am writing a blog, and I want there to be a like button, but I am curious, how can I get the button to update for everybody?

```html
<button onclick="like()">Like</button>
<span id="likecount">0</span>
```

and js

```js
function like(){
  document.getElementById('likecount').innerText++;
  //Toggle code here
}
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps use a database so that the count is stored? this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597922/how-to-create-your-own-like-button-not-facebook-related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to update the like just like FB/Twitter/etc do, you'll need a connection that allows the server to send updates to connected clients, without the clients requesting anything. This can be done using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) / [Socket.io](https://socket.io/), but needs a different infrastructure than standard blogs.

An alternative would be to save the like to a database, and [polling](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/polling-in-javascript-ab2d6378705a) the like data every few seconds. It's less fancy, but also less complex.